# using Telerik testing environment

Tags: c#, telerik

I am learning how to use the Telerik test environment. 
I created a test that runs through my program.  One of the steps is to create a repository, into which I will upload data. I would like to run this test numerous times as a load test, so the name needs to be dynamic. I would like to create a name such as "Repository_Date_Time, since no matter how many times I use it, uniqueness is guaranteed.

I created a code step right before the text box insertion step. I would like to generate a string, and then use it in the next step so that the repository is created with a unique name.

Code generated is: this is in the steps within the telerik application

```
     [WebTest_CodedStep] : New Coded Step
```

Then, within this step, I can hard code stuff:

```
    [CodedStep(@"New Coded Step")]
            public void WebTest_CodedStep()
            {

            }
```

I want to use something like this: `string currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");`

and then use the saveNow contained data as an ending to a string to make it unique, but it must be done within the following step:

```
Type 'Moshe-Master Repository Test01' into Item0Textboxchanged     
TypedText:               Moshe-Master Repository Test01
```

So that the red name will be substituted by a variable carrying the new string which I creatred.
The TypedText box is the value being typed automatically, and I would like to change it with the generated value from the previous step. Can a TypedText value be dynamic?

Thanks!

EDIT: I just realized that therre is a way to use a variable as input, however, I do not know where I can create it. The location where I can put it as input is in the top right state-chart with all current data being used for that particular step. (bindings) is set to collection at the moment. When I try to change it into a variable it tells me that the variable needs to be created- it does not specify where.

Comment: A question and a comment... The question: What have you tried thus far?  The comment: Sharing any code (good or bad) is a **much** better way to get a faster (and better) response.

Comment: Hi Brian, I added some code to my original post. I would appreciate any help, since I am on a time crunch. I have used the Telerik testing environment to run through my program, however, in order to automate the test I need to have a uniqie name for a repository which will be created by the program's automation.

Comment: Can you post the **actual** code (omitting anything proprietary) that you have written to attempt what you are doing?

Comment: There is really not too much code. The code is generated by Telerik while I am creating the test. All of these test steps are generated by the application. I am trying to create another manual coded step before a line that normally takes what I keyed in while creating the test. I want this value to be dynamic and change with every iteration.

Comment: Solved. I ended up using set and get, sort of global variables within environment.

Comment: Congrats on solving the problem!

Comment: Thanks- I do have another question, but rather than answering me I am getting trolled. Any chance of looking at my other question, Brian?

Comment: The one regarding `Silverlight`/`XAML`?

Comment: yes- That's the one. I never worked with either languages. I am a student, intern, still learning. My questions would probably be more informative if I knew more about it.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those technologies are things I work with on a regular basis so, I am afraid I won't be much help there :(